# Item replacing in lists not working right

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def itera_mundo(mundo):

    colunas = len(mundo[0])
    linhas = len(mundo)
    ncolunas = colunas + 2
    nlinhas = linhas + 2
    novo_mundo=cria_mundo(nlinhas,ncolunas)
    for linha in range(linhas):
        for coluna in range(colunas):
            if mundo[linha][coluna] == 1:
                novo_mundo[linha+1][coluna+1] = 1
    return novo_mundo

def cria_mundo(linhas, colunas):

    mini_matriz = []
    matriz = []
    for x in range(colunas):
        mini_matriz.append(0)
    for z in range(linhas):
        matriz.append(mini_matriz)
    return matriz

print(itera_mundo([[1,0],[0,0]]))
```

`cria_mundo` creates a matrix made out of 0s where `linhas` is the amount of lines and `colunas` is the amount of columns in the matrix. Each line consists of `colunas` elements, so basically if `linhas = 2` and `colunas = 3` it'd return a list like `[[0,0,0], [0,0,0]]`.

Now, I want to use `itera_mundo`, where `mundo` is also a matrix in a list. This function takes `cria_mundo` and adds 2 columns and 2 lines to the `mundo` matrix, one on each side, basically encasing the `mundo` matrix in a box of 0s.
That is how it's supposed to work, but it doesn't, because if `mundo` was `[[1,0], [0,1]]` it'd output `[[0,0,0,0], [0,1,0,0], [0,0,1,0], [0,0,0,0]]` but instead it outputs `[[0, 1, 1, 0], [0, 1, 1, 0], [0, 1, 1, 0], [0, 1, 1, 0]]` for some odd reason.

How could I fix this without imports, breaks or continues?

Comment: issue is in "for z in range(linhas):
        matriz.append(mini_matriz)" >> here we ar inseriting same "mini_matriz" as multiple entries in "matriz". should copy/clone "mini_matriz" before appeniding in to matriz.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    def itera_mundo(mundo):

        colunas = len(mundo[0])
        linhas = len(mundo)
        ncolunas = colunas + 2
        nlinhas = linhas + 2
        novo_mundo=cria_mundo(nlinhas,ncolunas)
        for linha in range(linhas):
            for coluna in range(colunas):
                if mundo[linha][coluna] == 1:
                    novo_mundo[linha+1][coluna+1] = 1
        return novo_mundo

    def cria_mundo(linhas, colunas):

        mini_matriz = []
        matriz = []
        for x in range(colunas):
            mini_matriz.append(0)
        for z in range(linhas):
            matriz.append(mini_matriz[:])
        return matriz

    print(itera_mundo([[1,0],[0,0]]))
```

output:

```
    >python mundo.py
    [[0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is my a solution.

```
def itera_mundo(mundo):
    colunas = len(mundo[0])+2
    linhas = len(mundo)+2
    novo_mundo=cria_mundo(linhas,colunas)
    for row in range(1,len(novo_mundo)-1):
        novo_mundo[row][1:-1] = mundo[row-1]
    return novo_mundo

def cria_mundo(linhas, colunas):
    return [[0 for c in range(colunas)] for l in range(linhas)]

print(itera_mundo([[1,0],[0,1]]))
```

Output

```
[[0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0]]
```